# Mail flow that only allows 1 PDF attachement?

Tags: office365, exchange

I need a mail flow that allows either `no attachments` or `only 1 PDF attachement` - if more than 1 attachement or other filetype than PDF, the mail flow rule must reply the sender with an "error" message to only send 1 PDF file.

Is that possible?

I can only see in the "New rule" that I have the attachement size - not count.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, there is no built-in way to limit the count of attachment in Office 365.

Comment: You could try to create an attachmentForwardingMailboxD, set a mailflow rule to put ALL emails with attachments inside, then create an inbox rule to forward them without attachments to original recipients (based on message headers).